# Match float or integer number

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to check is a String fits the requirements.
Now I have something like this:

```
String aaa = "322.155";
boolean match = aaa.matches("\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}"); //matches
String aaa = "32.155";
boolean match = aaa.matches("\\d{3}\\.\\d{3}"); //don't match
```

What I want is make all this numbers

```
1
2
999
22.22
333.23
1.012
```

match the pattern.
What pattern should I use?

```
boolean match = aaa.matches("\\d{1-3}\\.\\d{1-3}"); //isn't correct
```

Comment: What about `.345`, should it be considered valid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another possibility:

```
"\\d{1,3}(\\.\\d{1,3})?"
```

Matches one to three digits and, optionally, a decimal with another one to three trailing digits.

```
1        matches
2        matches
999      matches
22.22    matches
333.23   matches
1.012    matches
.123     does not match
1234     does not match
123.1234 does not match
1..2     does not match
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a non-specific quantifier:

```
"\\d+?\\.?\\d*"
```

This will match any 1+ digits, followed by a dot, followed by any 0+ digits.

**Test**

```
String[] test = {"1", "10", "1.1", "100.1000", "......................1", "0..2"};
for (String s: test) {
    System.out.println(s.matches("\\d+?\\.*\\d*"));
}
```

**Output**

```
true
true
true
true
false
false
```

**Note**

As the requirements are not too clear, if you need to cap the number of digits to match either before or after the separator, you can use the `{min,max}` quantifier idiom as explained by [hotzst](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5378766/hotzst), instead of a general quantifier.

Comment: @alex yeah just realized the dot was optional. Fixed now.

Comment: @Mena Why not? The `\\.*` matches 0 or more `.`s, doesn't it?

Comment: @resueman that's true. Wouldn't match your previous example, but would multiple dots in between - thanks for pointing out. (answer edited)

Comment: 34234.34234 also matches this pattern. And it shouldn't

Comment: @alex this is not very clear to me. Is there a limit of digits you need to match?

Comment: Your description should say `followed by any 0+ digits` instead of 1+.

Answer (score 1):

As the `.` is not mandatory

```
\\d+\\.?\\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
"\\d{1,3}\\.?\\d{0,3}"
```

Requires at least one number before the `.`, which is optional and up to three numbers behind.

Comment: This would match 111111 which might not fit the requirements, but not sure about that.

Comment: @Jamie there you are right. In this respect resueman's answer is better.